# Multipeer Connectivity iOS 7 m4a Audio Streaming

Tags: objective-c, ios7, multipeer-connectivity, nsinputstream

I'm using this tutorial http://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity,  and works nice for mp3, but  nothing with m4a, someone know a best way?  for play audio from  a NSInputStream  (MCSession didReceiveStream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the file to an MP3 then streaming it..

You can use something like [TPAACAudioConverter](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPAACAudioConverter), might help you out.

Multipeer connectivity is an awesome feat, enjoy using it! :)

good luck!

Comment: I was trying with lame but without results, This library is not only for convert MP3 to AAC M4A encoded?, one more thing in the library i mentioned, the problem to parse de data is when you call AudioFileStreamParseBytes() to decode bytes only works for MP3, for the other formats bytes, get a no supported file error.

Comment: I haven't tried it personally, but something to that affect should work.